# Sort empty or null to bottom always

Tags: javascript, sorting

The following is a natural sort function I pulled from somewhere I forget exactly.  I'm looking to modify it so that empty or null values always sort to the bottom regardless of asc/desc.

Here is what I have right now:

```
function gridNaturalSorter(a, b) {      
    if(a[sortcol])
        a = a[sortcol].replace(/<(?:.|\n)*?>/gm, '');
    if(b[sortcol]) 
        b = b[sortcol].replace(/<(?:.|\n)*?>/gm, '');

    if(b)
        b = b.toString().substr(0, 15);
    if(a)
        a = a.toString().substr(0, 15);

    var re = /(^([+\-]?(?:0|[1-9]\d*)(?:\.\d*)?(?:[eE][+\-]?\d+)?)?$|^0x[0-9a-f]+$|\d+)/gi, 
        sre = /(^[ ]*|[ ]*$)/g,
        dre = /(^([\w ]+,?[\w ]+)?[\w ]+,?[\w ]+\d+:\d+(:\d+)?[\w ]?|^\d{1,4}[\/\-]\d{1,4}[\/\-]\d{1,4}|^\w+, \w+ \d+, \d{4})/,
        hre = /^0x[0-9a-f]+$/i,
        ore = /^0/,
        i = function(s) { 
            return gridNaturalSorter.insensitive && (''+s).toLowerCase() || ''+s 
        },

        // convert all to strings strip whitespace
        x = i(a).replace(sre, '') || '',
        y = i(b).replace(sre, '') || '',

        // chunk/tokenize

        xN = x.replace(re, '\0$1\0').replace(/\0$/,'').replace(/^\0/,'').split('\0'),
        yN = y.replace(re, '\0$1\0').replace(/\0$/,'').replace(/^\0/,'').split('\0'),

        // numeric, hex or date detection

        xD = parseInt(x.match(hre)) || (xN.length != 1 && x.match(dre) && Date.parse(x)),
        yD = parseInt(y.match(hre)) || xD && y.match(dre) && Date.parse(y) || null,
        oFxNcL, oFyNcL;

        // first try and sort Hex codes or Dates
        if (yD)
            if ( xD < yD ) return -1;
        else if ( xD > yD ) return 1;

        // natural sorting through split numeric strings and default strings
        for(var cLoc=0, numS=Math.max(xN.length, yN.length); cLoc < numS; cLoc++) {
            // find floats not starting with '0', string or 0 if not defined (Clint Priest)
            oFxNcL = !(xN[cLoc] || '').match(ore) && parseFloat(xN[cLoc]) || xN[cLoc] || 0;
            oFyNcL = !(yN[cLoc] || '').match(ore) && parseFloat(yN[cLoc]) || yN[cLoc] || 0;

            // handle numeric vs string comparison - number < string - (Kyle Adams)
            if (isNaN(oFxNcL) !== isNaN(oFyNcL)) { 
                return (isNaN(oFxNcL)) ? 1 : -1; 
            }
            // rely on string comparison if different types - i.e. '02' < 2 != '02' < '2'
            else if (typeof oFxNcL !== typeof oFyNcL) {
                oFxNcL += '';
                oFyNcL += '';
            }
            if (oFxNcL < oFyNcL) 
                return -1;
            if (oFxNcL > oFyNcL) 
                return 1;
        }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And what's your problem?

Comment: You should add code in your question.

Comment: It wouldn't let me post that much code for some reason, looks like a mod added it for me.

Comment: Pretty early on you should be able to tell if it's going to be empty, so just add early `if` and return `-1` or `1` depending if it's `a` or `b`

Comment: @PaulS.: or 0 if both are empty or null.

Comment: Not exactly related, but which kind of arrays are you going to sort with this function? If there's all types of data in an array, it's badly designed, or not purposed to be sorted at the first place...

Comment: It is a generic function used to sort multiple columns in a table, could be ints or strings.

Comment: Then I'd forget "generic sorting" and took care of those particular types only. Sorting a large table using this function will take an hour ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know how to implement multiple comparators and a comparator that sorts `null` to bottom that's quite easy.

To implement multiple comparators, you just have to return the result of the first comparator that doesn't return `0`.

Here I also created a `withComparators` helper function that allows to compose multiple comparators together. If you understand this code you will be able to easily come up with your own solution for your specific problem.

*Note that your `gridNaturalSorter` function is a comparator just like `nullsToBottom` is in my example.*

E.g.

```
var items = ['test', null, 'test1', 'test3', null, 'test4'];


items.sort(withComparators(nullsToBottom, textAsc));
//["test", "test1", "test3", "test4", null, null]


function nullsToBottom(a, b) {
    return a === b? 0 : a === null? 1 : -1;
}

function textAsc(a, b) {
    return a < b? -1 : +(a > b);
}

function withComparators() {
    var comparators = arguments;

    return function (a, b) {
        var len = comparators.length, i = 0, result;

        for (; i < len; i++) {
            result = comparators[i](a, b);
            if (result) return result;
        }

        return 0;
    };
}
```

Comment: Kindly give the correct example code.

Comment: @JaiKumaresh not sure to understand your comment?

Comment: `var comparators = arguments;` this `arguments` means.? I can't able to understand your example code. Thanks for your reply :)